# Entity Framework Take N items of child collection

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Say I have a `Customer` entity, and a `Sales` entity, of 1-to-many relationship.
How could I get all Customers with N number of most recent sales?

```
var result = Customers.Where(c => c.Sales.Any());
```

This would return all customers with ALL their sales.
What if I want just 2 sales record from each customer?

P/S: I can do that with query syntax, i'm looking for method syntax solution. I just can't figure out how to chain them together in method syntax form

```
var result = from cust in context.Customers
             select new
             {
                 Customers = cust,
                 Sales = cust.Sales.OrderBy(s => s.Date).Take(2)
             };
```

This works, but i'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

EDIT:
OK, it turns out the query syntax that i included here is not working too.
Only the `Sales` in the anonymous type is effectively reduced to 2 records.

```
var filtered = result.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Customers);
```

doing this will still result in a list of customers with ALL their sales

Comment: could you post your query syntax query ?

Comment: updated with with query syntax code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a project as described in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx)

```
var dbquery = Customers.Select( c => new { 
                        Customer = c,
                        Sales = c.Sales.OrderBy(s => s.Date)
                             .Take(2).Select( s => new { s, s.SalesDetails})
                  });

var customers = dbquery 
   .AsEnumerable() 
   .Select(c => c.Customer);
```

Comment: just add the where clause for c.Sales.Any()

Comment: this still return me customers with ALL sales included :(

Comment: @Taetsu Disable lazy loading before you access `Sales` property by setting `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: turning the `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` does the trick, however, this causing another problem, now the related entities no longer load. I got null object reference trying to access `s.SalesDetails`. .Include() doesn't help too.

Comment: It seems `.Include()` can't apply when you project your query. It is working as expected if I take out the project.

Comment: @Taetsu Yes. `Include` is not considered when you project.

Comment: So how should I get around this problem? My brain is suffering meltdown now